# How to make a form and button editable in a div with z-index -1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, button

I have gotten a design which has a simple input field in a field with z-`index: -1;`

But the input field is not editable and the button doesn't react. I reckon it has to do with z-index. Is there a way to have the input field always be editable / focus and the button always be clickable

this is part of the page i have, the input field and button is in the background div. http://www.bootply.com/z5B5YBWS5Y

The other div's will scroll on over the input field, but i would like the input field be editable and button clickable even if the sillioutte is on top.

Comment: `z-index: 1 !important;`?

Answer (score 0):

`z-index:-1` on the form alone won't cause this. The click events are most likely hitting an element on top of your inputs.

You can set `pointer-events:none` in CSS on the offending element if you don't need users to be able to click on it (in which case the pointer events will pass through to the form). I suspect that the best solution is to figure out how to bring that form to the surface of the page, though.

Comment: i have change z-index: 0 and now it reacts only if the other divs are not in front of it. But i like the input field always be editable, see the boot ply link. I like the button to be clickable even behind the buildings .png image
*I have seen it somewhere :(

Comment: So what i mean you can interact with the elements as long as you can see them

Comment: pointer-events: none on the buildings is your solution then. The buildings won't recognize the clicks and the clicks will register on the first thing under it. If you could redo the buildings as an svg instead of an image, you might be able to get clicks to register as long as the element is visible and the user is clicking on a part of the form that is visible. The element could potentially BE the shape of the buildings if defined by svg path.

Comment: i have rephrased my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32712881/using-css-shape-to-click-being-an-image