# Using css shape to click being an image?

Tags: html, css, shapes, css-shapes

I am trying to get an input field and button to work even when they are behind a shaped png image.

[image]

Now i thought all i had to do was using shape and it would trace the shape. And the button or input field would be editable/clickable

.element {
    float: left;
    height: 150px;
    width: 1300px;
    shape-outside: img('path/to/red-image-with-shape.png');
}

[image]

ps: this situation is a screenshot when an user scrolls upwards. The designer wants the form elements to be accessible even with these scrolling situation.

Comment: Try adding pointer-events:none; on the .element. Will not work in IE10 and below though.

Comment: your browser isn't that clever. Clicking on an area will click the item with the highest z-index, and so no, you cannot do this.

Comment: @Harry,No it's the top part of a div which scrolls upwards. The designer wants the form elements to be accessable even when this is the scrolling position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set  `pointer-events: none` to the element with the shape. As far as I know there is no other solution. 
Maybe you could try to make input field transparent and change the z-index. But that would not be what you want. By the way it is not user-friendly to hide the content of the input field.

Comment: Yes! i had to put the `pointer-events: none;` on the most outtter div but it kinda works thanks. Total new element for me